# Lets combine all the awk tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

**UPDATE:** all awk variant tags have now been defined to be synonyms for the one tag, `awk`, so the below discussion is now only retained by request for historical purposes.

Not really looking for an answer, just to get the attention of people who look at awk questions.

There are questions being posted that are general to awk but only tagged with gawk, mawk, or nawk depending on which awk variant the OP **thinks** they are using (in which case people who could help them don't see the question as they're looking at awk tags, not just gawk tags), and there are others which are tagged with all 4 of awk, gawk, mawk, and nawk or various subsets thereof (which is just a waste of time). We don't have tags for some other awk variants (e.g. BSD awk) nor do we have tags for GNU or BSD sed variants, or various other tools variants, and we simply don't need all those awk tags since they aren't used consistently or accurately and on those rare occasions where someone specifically needs an answer for 1 specific variant they can just say that in  the question.

A few years ago [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/synonyms) we got all of the awk variants listed as synonyms for `awk` so now we only have to look at the `awk` tag to find all awk questions - please go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/awk/synonyms and upvote the 3 listed synonyms so we can get the same result here.

Comment: FWIW merging seems a reasonable idea to me

Comment: "Sorry, I'll delete this once the goal is met." -- please don't. It's useful to have some record of the discussion, even if it's just one paragraph and a straightforward subject.

Comment: @ilkkachu OK, I'll leave it as long as it doesn't start gathering down/close votes. All tags are now synonyms so we're done.

Comment: Yes, I gave the final vote for mawk... The only thing I'm worried about is the tag wikis... mawk didn't have one, but gawk well may have had at least something.

Comment: @ilkkachu don't worry, it will use the target one.

Comment: Title should have been "This is getting [awk]ward..."