# Should we have specific tags for individual machine-readable code types?

Tags: discussion, tags

A new tag [qr-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qr-code) has recently been created.

I voted "reject" in the "suggested edit" [review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/364265) as I felt it was not a good idea to have a tag describing a *specific* machine-readable code, considering that there are so many types of them. I would think it more reasonable to have only one "barcode" or "code reading" tag that applies to all problems concerning generation and interpretation of such codes, given that the scope of site is "Unix/Linux" and not "Machine Vision". (There was a [similar discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5652/377345) that led to the merging of all `awk` tags some months ago).

So the question which I would like to put up for discussion is whether that tag should be abandoned in favor of/changed to a general "code reading" tag. We could still have tags for individual programs used to read or generate such codes, if and when such programs are seen to cause problems frequently enough to warrant a tag of their own.